# ASP Routing to a folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

In an ASP MVC4 website, how do I route requests for **all files** in a **sub folder** to a route?

For example, is it possible to route URL requests to:

- `http://site/Assets/template.css` --> `~/Site1/Assets/subfolder/template.css`?
- `http://site/Assets/a.png` --> `~/Site1/Assets/subfolder/a.png`?

I would like to be able to dynamically register these on app_start as I cannot predict what the name of the subfolder will be until that time.

Comment: Why do you want to register routes for assets. 
You can use bundling and get the assets from any subfolder.
You can also add the scripts and css in the _layout and just use the configuration value.`<script src="@Url.Content("YourFolderNameFromConfiguration" + "/someimage.png")" ></script>`

Comment: I have some areas which are 'pluggable'. I do not know all of the folder names until `App_start`. These areas need their own assets such as images and css.

Comment: What's your purpose? If you have assets folder in your root you can always use "/Assets/a.png" everywhere.

Comment: I would like to be able to point all requests to a URL to route to a specific folder. The technical purpose is so that I can request `http://foo/Assets` and the contents of that folder are served from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this help?

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
  var folderName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssetFolderName"];

  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/" + folderName + "/css");
}
```

Comment: This would help for css files, however for images and other assets I don't think this would solve the problem. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: For images you probably cannot use the same approach. Instead of using the literal path "../SomeFolder/Someimage.png", you can have a dynamic property which will hold the path of the folder and which can be later used in your views! something like `<img src="../@ViewBag.AssetFolder/buttons.gif""/>` and you can define the folder in your ActionExecuting or some event!